# CefSharp initialization is not called

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I have now run ten copies of the program. four were frozen. please explain why Cef initialization is not called

```
     private static ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;

     public static void InitializeBrowser()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("InitializeBrowser() -> start");
        if (Cef.IsInitialized)
            Console.WriteLine("InitializeBrowser() -> IsInitialized");

        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings(), performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

        AutoResetEvent waitHandleOnBrowserInitialized = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        EventHandler onBrowserInitialized = null;

        onBrowserInitialized = async (sender, e) =>
        {
            _browser.BrowserInitialized -= onBrowserInitialized;
            Console.WriteLine("InitializeBrowser() -> -=onBrowserInitialized");

            waitHandleOnBrowserInitialized.Set();
        };

        _browser.BrowserInitialized += onBrowserInitialized;

        Console.WriteLine("InitializeBrowser() -> +=onBrowserInitialized");

        waitHandleOnBrowserInitialized.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("InitializeBrowser() -> finish");
}
```

the initialization process freezes

[image]

Comment: Best guess would be that BrowserInitialized is called before you have subscribed. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3552#issuecomment-841582103

Comment: thank you the solution helped, today I learned a little more